# Drag & Drop Selenium WebDriver + java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пробовал следующее:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
   .click(someElement)
   .click(someOtherElement)
   .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

Action selectMultiple = builder.build();
selectMultiple.perform();
```

и

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
   .moveToElement(otherElement)
   .release(otherElement)
   .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

а так же

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source")); 

WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Смещать мышь по осям на (1, 1) так же пробовал. Ничего из этого не помогло. `ChromeDriver` вообще поддерживает это действие? Если да, то может есть варианты как это еще можно реализовать?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, переьащить один элемент во фрейм другого. Как и  написано в вопросе, а так же понятно из приведенных примеров кода

Comment: вот [тут](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop) у меня работает на последнем хроме. а у вас?

Comment: попробовал все 3 способа, приведенных в вопросе. Ничего. Скачал новый драйвер - эффект нулевой. Версия хрома тоже последняя.
Тест проходит, не падает. Однко элементы остаются на своих местах

Comment: Версия драйвера 2.36. С более поздними тесты не запускаются. может быть дело в этом?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor можно подробней об окружении? Версию хрома, версию драйвера. Может быть пример работаюего кода?

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.34.522932, Mac OSX 10.13.3, Версия 65.0.3325.146 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит). код, как у вас: moveTo и release

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, ну тогда я в замешательстве. Не работает ни на windows 7/8 в последних версиях chrome с драйверов 2.34 и 2.36, ни на маке с тем же драйвером и последним хромом

Comment: тогда используйте вариант с JS. у меня никогда не работало unfocus с элемента, поэтому использовал JS

Answer (score 0):

возможно, какие-то проблемы с браузером или драйвером...

Попробуем решить данную задачу через JavaScript

```
function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {},
        setData: function (key, value) {
            this.data[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return this.data[key];
        }
    };
    return event;
}
function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) {
    if (transferData !== undefined) {
        event.dataTransfer = transferData;
    }
    if (element.dispatchEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.type, event);
    }
}
function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) {
    var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);
    var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');
    dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);
    var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer);
}
```

Дальше нужно вызвать метод simulateHTML5DragAndDrop

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scriptOnTop + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1])", source, target);
```